# Java org.neo4j.driver.v1 Unable to connect to Neo4j 3.3.2

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I have a neo4j database set up which I've logged into via the browser and properly set up the password:

The following **python** code WORKS:

```
>>> from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
>>> driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "pass"))
```

However when I try connecting with **Java** (org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:1.4.4):

```
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver( "bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "pass") );
```

I get a constant connection refused:

```
org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to connect to localhost:7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

This leads to be believe that there is some kind of authentication issue going on (wrong password?) but that obviously isn't the case since I am connecting successfully via Python.